# How to work with substrings in VB?

Tags: vb.net

It won't let me put in a surname less than five letters

```
    Dim firstintial As String 
    Dim form As String
    Dim secondname As String


    form = TextBox3.Text
    firstintial = TextBox4.Text
    secondname = TextBox5.Text

    firstintial = firstintial.Substring(0, 2)
    secondname = secondname.Substring(0, 5)


    Dim newusername As String
    newusername = form & secondname & firstintial
    TextBox6.Text = newusername

    Dim newpassword As String
    newpassword = TextBox7.Text
    TextBox8.Text = newpassword



    If TextBox7.Text = TextBox12.Text Then
        Label13.Text = "correct"
    Else
        Label13.Text = "try again"
```

Comment: You should read the documentation of Substring. You're asking to get the first 5 letters with secondname. If there are less than 5 letters, your program will be confused. "Why I'm I told to get the first 5 letters when there are only 3? I don't know what to do."

Answer (score 1):

[`Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't like if index + length indicates a position outside of the string.

```
Dim length = Math.Min(firstintial.Length, 2)
firstintial = firstintial.Substring(0, length)
length = Math.Min(secondname.Length, 5)
secondname = secondname.Substring(0, length)
```

Answer (score 1):

Although many people frown upon using Visual Basic-specific methods instead of .NET framework methods, you can use [`Left`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.left(v=vs.110).aspx), which takes care of the requested length being greater than the length of the string:

```
secondname = Left(s, 5)
```

However, if you are using it in code on a control, the `Control.Left` property gets chosen in preference, so you need to qualify it:

```
secondname = Strings.Left(s, 5)
```

Comment: Pedantic note, I don't think it's quite right to call the method VB-specific; I'm pretty sure you could call it from C# with the correct references and `using` statements.  It's more accurate to call it a VBA compatibility function.

Comment: @Craig LEFT$ has been in BASIC since before VBA was even conceived.

Comment: The history wasn't my point, my point was that for me, "VB-specific" implies that it's not available to other languages, which as of .NET seems not to be the case.  It's a pretty minor distinction, since it would be very unusual to call into the VBA compatibility material from other languages, which was why I noted that it was "pedantic".

Comment: @Craig It is *not* VBA "compatibility". It is part of the Basic language. I would offer to take this to chat where it would be interesting to discuss each other's point of view, but I don't have the time right now as I'm five hours ahead of you.

Comment: My apologies, I forgot about how VB.NET brings in the old string manipulation functions through `Strings`.  That having been said, the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.` part above should be unnecessary, it should be fine to call it as either `Strings.Left` or just plain `Left`.  In that form, it is unambigously part of the language.  (I might still quibble with accessing it through `Microsoft.VisualBasic`.)

Comment: @Craig Thanks, that makes sense. Answer modified accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq's `Take` to get up to number of characters without an explicit test:

```
Dim firstinitial = New String(TextBox4.Text.Take(2).ToArray())
Dim secondname = New String(TextBox5.Text.Take(5).ToArray())
```

I would expect this to be less efficient than the `Substring`-based code, so be careful about using it in a tight loop, but it should be just fine for something that looks like it's done in one pass.